# JQuery Datepicker function always returns a null value for the date

Tags: jquery, html, forms, spring, datepicker

I have recently been working on something that has got me stumped.

I am using `Spring 3.0` with its built in validation along with `Hibernate 3.6`.

I am trying to use a `JQuery` datepicker to enter in dates from the user. However, the date that gets sent to my controller is always null and is wreaking havoc with my Spring Validation.

i always get this error

```
    javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes       [dao.Appointments] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=appointment_date, rootBeanClass=class dao.Appointments, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
```

I found out that this error is occuring because the date that is sent to my controllers is "null" so i went back to look at my values for my dates from my JSP

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
            });
        </script>

            <!-- <script>
                $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
                });
            </script> -->


            <script>
            function validateForm()
            {
                var x=document.forms["makeAppointmentForm"]["datepicker"].value;
                if (x==null || x=="")
                {
                    alert("Date must be selected");
                    return false;
                }

                var y=document.forms["makeAppointmentForm"]["desDoctor"].value;
                if (y==null || y=="")
                {
                    alert("Your desired doctor must be filled in");
                    return false;
                }   
            }   
            </script>
```

The Code above is what i have in my JSP i tried a couple versions of the datepicker but still get a "null" value for my date. I used Javascript validation for my fields.

```
<form name ="makeAppointmentForm" action="makeAppointment" method="post"     onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<font>When selecting the date, Please click in the date field and a drop down menu will appear so that you may click on the date. 
The system will do the rest!!!</font><br>

Please select your desired date of appointment: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="text"/><br><br>
```

The code above is where i use the datepicker for the user to enter in their desired date.
   I put println statements in my code to try and see where the dates come up as null and so far, it is "null" from the very start. I have tried other formulations of the JQuery datepicker that i found on stackoverflow but it always comes out to the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you confuse the `name` and `id` attributes of the `input` tag. `document.forms` use the name attribute, not the id.

`document.forms["makeAppointmentForm"]["datepicker"].value` will always be null if you don't add `name="datepicker"` to the input tag.

Same thing for `Spring`, it use the name attribute to map the input value to a request parameter.

Adding the name attribute should solve your problem :

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="text"/>
```

Comment: OH!! Thanks Jean-Philippe, that fixed it!!